# Having issue in uploading numeric and alphanumeric values to sql database in C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

[image]I have attached the screenshot of excel file which is being uploaded to process. It is around 80000 rows. Whenever I am uploading excel file to sql server 2008 r2 database, numeric values get updated but alphanumeric values not getting updated(Becoming blank as shown in the screenshot). If I Put alhanumeric in the first row or next sheet it will get updated. I have attached the c# code and oledb connection string for reading excel file. Please do help me to resolve this issue. I have tried simple trim() also for avoiding blank space.

Code

```
            string oleconstr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1""";

            using (OleDbConnection olecon = new OleDbConnection(oleconstr))
            {

                olecon.Open();
                OleDbCommand olecmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", olecon);
                OleDbDataReader olerd = olecmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (olerd.Read())
                {                       
                    string col1 = "", col2 = "", ex = "", efdt = "", deldt = "";

                    if (olerd[0].ToString() != string.Empty && olerd[1].ToString() != string.Empty && olerd[5].ToString() != string.Empty)
                    {
                        col1 = olerd[0].ToString().TrimStart().TrimEnd();
                        col2 = olerd[1].ToString().TrimStart().TrimEnd();
                        ex = Convert.ToString(olerd[2].ToString()).Trim();
                        efdt = Convert.ToString(olerd[3].ToString()).TrimStart().TrimEnd();
                        deldt = Convert.ToString(olerd[4].ToString());
```

..........
..........
..........

[image]

Comment: Show us your table structure and column types.

Comment: First thing to do: work out whether the problem is reading from Excel, or writing to SQL. You're currently working with two different systems - narrowing it down to just *one* system will mean there's less to worry about.